# If-then statement issues

Tags: java, if-statement

This is the sample program which uses if statements to pop out test scores using user input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testscore
{
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println ("Enter test score: ");
    int testscore = sc.nextInt();
    char grade;

    if (testscore >= 90) {
        grade = 'A';
    } else if (testscore >= 80) {
        grade = 'B';
    } else if (testscore >= 70) {
        grade = 'C';
    } else if (testscore >= 60) {
        grade = 'D';
    } else {
        grade = 'F';
    }
    System.out.println("Grade = " + grade);
}
}
```

and this is the program I created for drink tests

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class drinktest
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println ("Enter The Amount Of Drinks You've Had: ");
    int drinknumber = sc.nextInt();
    char sober;

    if (drinknumber <=2) {sober = 'A';}
    else if (drinknumber <=3) {sober = 'B';}
    else if (drinknumber <=4) {sober = 'C';}
    else if (drinknumber <=5) {sober = 'D';}
    else if (drinknumber >=5) {sober = 'F';}

    System.out.println ("Your sobreity grade is: " + sober);
}
}
```

The problem that I have is that everything works fine until the last line where it tells me that my variable isn't initialized. I did NOT get that error in the first program and to my knowledge they are identical.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You are missing a final else statement!

Comment: There's no `else` after the `>= 5`, it means that there exists a flow in which you get to the last line with `sober` not initialized.

Comment: `URGENT HELP PLEASE`, Why your question is more important?

Comment: Its urgent because this is due in 10 minutes

Comment: damn. sorry for asking for help I guess.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the Java compiler knows, there may be a flow where none of the conditionals are met, and this `sober` won't be initialized.
Just change your last `else if` to an `else`, and you should be fine:

```
if (drinknumber <=2) {sober = 'A';}
else if (drinknumber <=3) {sober = 'B';}
else if (drinknumber <=4) {sober = 'C';}
else if (drinknumber <=5) {sober = 'D';}
else {sober = 'F';} // If none of the if's were met, it must be more than 5.
```

Comment: When I did this, it gave me an error

Comment: care to share the error?

Answer (score 1):

```
char sober = 0;
```

Use the above code.

Comment: the above answer is better :)

Answer (score 0):

You must first initialize the `sober` variable:
`char sober = 'F';`

And then, after you initialize the variable you can do the if statements.
But now you don't need to check for the 'F' grade (it is initialized as 'F') so just skip this part: 
`else if (drinknumber >=5) {sober = 'F';}`

After that we are left with:

```
char sober = 'F';

if (drinknumber <=2) {sober = 'A';}
else if (drinknumber <=3) {sober = 'B';}
else if (drinknumber <=4) {sober = 'C';}
else if (drinknumber <=5) {sober = 'D';}

System.out.println ("Your sobreity grade is: " + sober);
```